# Numeric keyboard with Touch ID on Mac Studio

Tags: mac, startup, touch-id

I have a numeric keyboard with Touch ID for my Mac Studio.

Installed it and registered my fingerprint.

I was under the impression that Touch ID would also work at a "cold" startup/boot as well as on a re-start, but it doesn't. Buttons Touch ID to unlock & autofilling passwords both on in settings. I don't get the choice on the start-up screen between a password or fingerprint.

I've been searching on the net but cannot find any clues... other than use Touch ID to get mac out of sleep, which in my case works flawlessly.

So am I correct in understanding that the touch id option is **only** available for - unlock your Mac from sleep - purchases - auto filling - user switching?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to how the iPhone deals with Touch ID [idk about Face ID, don't have anything using it] - periodically [seems to be about every two days] it will require your PIN on wake rather than Touch ID. This is I suppose a kind of 2FA.

On the Mac they seems to have decided to do this check at boot instead, perhaps on the assumption that people do actually periodically shut down or reboot their Mac far more frequently than their phone.

The end result is you need your password at boot. I've not known it ask at any other time.

Comment: so its seems to be both boot & restart. ths.